BottomSheetFragment flies to the top of the screen when animation or layout size change is executed
I have bottom sheet fragment with a couple of text fields. When i applying error on one of EditText's, bottom sheet flies to the top of the screen. My hypothesis is that this thing happening becouse of TextInputLayout's expand animation and size change when error message is appearing. Heres the implemenetation.
Heres the layout of bottom sheet:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_16">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/publication" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_close"
            style="@style/ButtonCloseDialog" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_link_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_16"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_bar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:text="@string/link" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/link_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_link_title"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_16"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/link_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/link_hint" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_16"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/link_layout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_16"
        android:text="@string/naming" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/name_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_name_title"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_16"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/name_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/publication_hint" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.divider.MaterialDivider
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_16"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:dividerColor="@color/divider_color" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_16"
        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_12"
        android:text="@string/add" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Base abstract bottom sheet class:
abstract class BaseBottomSheetDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private val dialogPeekHeight = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels

    protected open val isFullScreen: Boolean = false

    protected open val hasHalfExpandedState: Boolean = false

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // R.drawable.background_bottom_sheet_dialog is just a rectangle drawable with top corners round
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_bottom_sheet_dialog)

        setupDialog()
    }

    private fun setupDialog() {
        val dialogLayout = dialog?.findViewById<FrameLayout>(
            com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet
        ) ?: return

        if (isFullScreen) {
            dialogLayout.layoutParams.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        }

        if (!hasHalfExpandedState) {
            val bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(dialogLayout)
            bottomSheetBehavior.peekHeight = dialogPeekHeight
        }
    }
}

Bottom sheet fragment:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class BottomSheetFragment : BaseBottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private val binding: FragmentBottomSheetBinding by viewBinding()
    private val viewModel: BottomSheetViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_publication_sheet, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        with(binding) {
            btnClose.setOnClickListener { dismiss() }
            addButton.setOnClickListener { dismiss() }
            linkField.onTextChanged { viewModel.validateLink(it) }
            nameField.onTextChanged { viewModel.validateName(it) }
        }

        with(viewModel) {
            collectInViewScope(canAdd, ::onCanAdd)
            collectInViewScope(linkValidation, ::onLinkValidation)
        }
    }

    private fun onLinkValidation(validation: ValidationResult) {
        binding.linkLayout.error = validation.messageOrNull
    }

    private fun onCanAdd(isEnabled: Boolean) {
        binding.addButton.isEnabled = isEnabled
    }
}

Error applies to the edit text by collectInViewScope(linkValidation, ::onLinkValidation). This is just an extension that collects error flow from ViewModel.
I tried the answer in this on link with getting rid of android:animateLayoutChanges="true". But his doesn't work. Also i tried to put android:animateLayoutChanges="false" to it, but result is the same.
